# Ошибка в объявлении переменных double

Tags: c, double

```
main(){
   double y,t,j,h,T,Y,G,W; //выдает ошибку в этом месте

   printf ("y=");               
   scanf("%lf",&y);         
   printf ("t=");               
   scanf("%lf",&t);         
   printf("j=");                          
   scanf("%lf",&j);                   
   printf ("h=");                        
   scanf("%lf",&h);     

   if (G>1,1)               
       W=G+Y-lnT;          
   else                 
       W=pow(h,2)+78+pow((J-t),1\2)-pow(y,6);                 

   printf("W=%3.4lf \n",W);
   system("PAUSE");         
   return 0;
}
```

[image: скрин]

Comment: Приведите текст ошибки с указанием номера предложения, где возникает ошибка.

Comment: Функция main должна быть объявлена с типом возвращаемого значения nt, то есть int main( void )

Comment: Слеши у комментариев у вас не в ту сторону. Должно быть так `//`

Comment: Почему код в вопросе не совпадает с кодом на скриншоте? И, надо заметить, `if (G>1,1)` делает совсем не то, что вы думаете.

Answer (score 0):

Раз в функции main есть оператор:

```
return 0;
```

значит - эта функция ВОЗВРАЩАЕТ значение!
Раз она возвращает значения, значит в объявлении функции д.б. указан ТИП возвращаемого значения. О чём Вам чёрным по английски и сказал компилятор...